# DbCommandBuilder not working as expected

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, oledb, oledbcommand

I want to fetch data from a database table modify it and update it without being dependent on the database provider and the database structure, because it will be part of a library.

My first attempt was as follows:

```
'factory defined somewhere else as DbProviderFactory
'connection is a working DbConnection
Dim selectcmd As DbCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
Dim adapter As DbDataAdapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter()
Dim builder As DbCommandBuilder = factory.CreateCommandBuilder()

selectcmd.Connection = connection
selectcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl1"
adapter.SelectCommand = selectcmd
builder.DataAdapter = adapter

Dim ds As New DataSet
'Fetch data
adapter.Fill(ds)

'Change something in ds

adapter.Update(ds) '<- exception occurs
```

This did not work because the `CommandBuilder` did not generate the `Update-`, `Insert-` and `DeleteCommand` automatically although the documentation said it should do.

But even when I added

```
adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand()
adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand()
adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand()
```

it did not work. After further investigation I figured out that the `Commands` the `CommandBuilder` generated were useless, because it inserted `?` instead of `@param1` for all `Parameters`. It generated something like `INSERT INTO tbl1 (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)` for the `InsertCommand`

I would really like to use the CommandBuilder, because it is simple and I don't have something complicated like `JOINS`.

Comment: What Db are you using?  `?` looks right for Access, and maybe for others.

Comment: For testing I used OleDb with an Access mdb

Comment: And did it fail/work with Access? In the 2nd part you say "t did not work" that is totally unhelpful. Always describe what happened, what you expected etc.

Comment: Yes - it throws an OleDbException with the error message "Syntax error in INSERT INTO-clause"

Comment: Maybe your factory is yielding the wrong types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your your table contains column names that are reserved words in access, here there are :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738

you should change column names or even better use list them in select clause and use [ and ], something like this

```
select [username], [password], [time] from tbl1
```

Comment: That really solved the problem! I had two columns named "Section" and "Value" which are reserved words. Thank you very much!